# Unable to pass a fetched date dynamically to PL/SQL execute immediate

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to pass a fetched date to a query that i'm using inside the execute immediate but i'm getting the following error:

"DATE_X" : invalid identifier

This is my code:

```
declare
    DATE_X DATE;
    
begin
    SELECT to_date(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD') INTO DATE_X
    FROM XYZ;
    
    execute immediate "I want to use DATE_X in one query"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code, fixed, looks like this.

Sample table first:

```
SQL> create table xyz as select '2022-02-26' as value from dual;

Table created.
```

Anonymous PL/SQL block; I'm "using" `date_x` to count number of rows in Scott's EMP table whose `hiredate` is *less than* `date_x`.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    DATE_X DATE;
  3    l_cnt  number;
  4  begin
  5    SELECT to_date(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD') INTO DATE_X FROM XYZ;
  6
  7    execute immediate 'select count(*) from emp where hiredate < :a'
  8      into l_cnt using date_x;
  9    dbms_output.put_line('Result = ' || l_cnt);
 10  end;
 11  /
Result = 14

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```